# Need to add the totals from each of these queries into a single total amount

Tags: sql

```
SELECT Salary
    FROM Agent
    JOIN Person ON Agent.Agent_ID = Person.Person_ID
WHERE First_Name = 'Sarah' AND Last_Name = 'Murray'

UNION

SELECT SUM(Revenue*Commission)
    FROM Agent
        JOIN Person ON Agent.Agent_ID = Person.Person_ID
        JOIN Performance ON Agent.Agent_ID = Performance.Agent_ID
    WHERE First_Name = 'Sarah' AND Last_Name = 'Murray' AND YEAR(Performance_Date)=2014

    UNION

SELECT SUM(Total_Amount*Commission)
    FROM Agent
        JOIN Person ON Agent.Agent_ID = Person.Person_ID
        JOIN Band ON Person.Person_ID = Band.Primary_Contact_ID
        JOIN Album ON Band.Band_Id = Album.Band_ID
        JOIN Item ON Album.Album_Id = Item.Item_Id
        JOIN Order_Detail ON Item.Item_ID = Order_Detail.Item_ID
        JOIN Order_Header ON Order_detail.Order_ID = Order_Header.Order_ID
    WHERE First_Name = 'Sarah' AND Last_Name = 'Murray' AND YEAR(Order_Date)=2014
```

Results in:

```
43321.770000
48448.836000
94973.011200
```

Now I have tried doing something like aliasing each one and then doing something like Select SUM(Alias1, Alias2, Alias3) or maybe it should be SUM(Alias1 + Alias2 + Alias3)

```
SELECT SUM(Alias1, Alias2, Alias3)

FROM (SELECT Salary
    FROM Agent
    JOIN Person ON Agent.Agent_ID = Person.Person_ID
WHERE First_Name = 'Sarah' AND Last_Name = 'Murray') Alias1,

(SELECT SUM(Revenue*Commission)
    FROM Agent
        JOIN Person ON Agent.Agent_ID = Person.Person_ID
        JOIN Performance ON Agent.Agent_ID = Performance.Agent_ID
    WHERE First_Name = 'Sarah' AND Last_Name = 'Murray' AND YEAR(Performance_Date)=2014) Alias2,

(SELECT SUM(Total_Amount*Commission)
    FROM Agent
        JOIN Person ON Agent.Agent_ID = Person.Person_ID
        JOIN Band ON Person.Person_ID = Band.Primary_Contact_ID
        JOIN Album ON Band.Band_Id = Album.Band_ID
        JOIN Item ON Album.Album_Id = Item.Item_Id
        JOIN Order_Detail ON Item.Item_ID = Order_Detail.Item_ID
        JOIN Order_Header ON Order_detail.Order_ID = Order_Header.Order_ID
    WHERE First_Name = 'Sarah' AND Last_Name = 'Murray' AND YEAR(Order_Date)=2014) Alias3
```

But those don't work, just errors. My total should be around 186,743.6172 or the total of the above numbers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` in the form:

```
select sum(salary)
from (
  -- query 1 here
  union all
  -- query 2 here
  union all
  -- query 3 here
) x
```

In your case this could translate to:

```
select sum(salary)
from (
  SELECT Salary
    FROM Agent
    JOIN Person ON Agent.Agent_ID = Person.Person_ID
  WHERE First_Name = 'Sarah' AND Last_Name = 'Murray'
 union all
  SELECT SUM(Revenue*Commission)
    FROM Agent
        JOIN Person ON Agent.Agent_ID = Person.Person_ID
        JOIN Performance ON Agent.Agent_ID = Performance.Agent_ID
    WHERE First_Name = 'Sarah' AND Last_Name = 'Murray' 
      AND YEAR(Performance_Date)=2014
 union all
  SELECT SUM(Total_Amount*Commission)
    FROM Agent
        JOIN Person ON Agent.Agent_ID = Person.Person_ID
        JOIN Band ON Person.Person_ID = Band.Primary_Contact_ID
        JOIN Album ON Band.Band_Id = Album.Band_ID
        JOIN Item ON Album.Album_Id = Item.Item_Id
        JOIN Order_Detail ON Item.Item_ID = Order_Detail.Item_ID
        JOIN Order_Header ON Order_detail.Order_ID = Order_Header.Order_ID
    WHERE First_Name = 'Sarah' AND Last_Name = 'Murray' 
      AND YEAR(Order_Date)=2014
) x
```

Comment: @PaulSkains: if you feel this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.